# Lettrine with EB Garamond Initials

Tags: fonts, typography, lettrine, drop-cap

I want to print initials in the `EB Garamond Initials` font with the `lettrine` package. However, the text is overlapping the initial below. Am I doing something wrong with the setup?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface{\initials}{EB Garamond Initials}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\usepackage{lettrine}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{5}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\initials}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lettrine{L}{orem ipsum} dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you are cutting out 5 lines, do you want to cut out 7 or make the initial smaller?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Let's say make the initial smaller. I basically only changed `DefaultLines` to make the effect more visable.

Comment: Try setting the length `\DefaultDepth` to a positive value, say 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to add lines with the parameter depth=2 . Here, the space below becomes too large, so you can decrease the size of the lettrin with the lowersize=-0.1 parameter and depth=1, which leaves an extra space above that you decrease with lraise=0.1.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface{\initials}{EB Garamond Initials}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\usepackage{lettrine}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{5}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\initials}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lettrine[depth=1]% Add 1 line
    {L}{orem ipsum} dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. \lipsum[2]
\bigskip

        \lettrine[depth=2]% Add 2 lines
    {L}{orem ipsum} dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. \lipsum[2]
 \bigskip

        \lettrine[depth=1, loversize=-0.1]%add 1 line and 10% decrease.
    {L}{orem ipsum} dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. \lipsum[2]
\bigskip

        \lettrine[depth=1, loversize=-0.1, lraise=0.1]%add 1 line, 10% decrease and Go up 10%.
    {L}{orem ipsum} dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: lettrine-examples]

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that EB Garamond initials have a depth, which is about 40% of the height. At 10pt font size, the height of L is 7.39227pt, its depth is 2.87pt.

This shows why, when you reserve five lines for the height, two lines are overlapped.

You can play with `loversize` and `lraise`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin]{babel}% just to avoid overfull boxes

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{lettrine}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% fonts
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\newfontface{\initials}{EB Garamond Initials}

% lettrine settings
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{5}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLraise}{0.25}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{-0.25}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\initials}


\begin{document}

\lettrine{L}{orem ipsum} dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The following code after `\begin{document}` will print the dimensions for the letter L in EB Garamond Initials:

```
{\initials\xdef\initialsfont{\the\font}}
\noindent
Height: \the\fontcharht\initialsfont`L \\
Depth: \the\fontchardp\initialsfont`L
```

[image]

Comment: How do the numbers 7.39pt and 2.87pt relate to the parameters passed to `\DefaultLraise` and `\DefaultLoversize` ?

Comment: @Tommiie I guess I did trial and error.

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter. I discovered I can only use the letters "A", "G", "T" so I need to find a different solution. Thanks anyway.